# Hadoop java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.letoy.main.utils.NameCount$MyMapper not found

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I try to run the job with the Spring Boot, but it always tell me that the mapper class not found. I've already set the jarClass and upload the whole application to the server.

```
private static Configuration getConfiguration() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.addResource("../resources/core-site.xml");
        configuration.addResource("../resources/hdfs-site.xml");
        configuration.addResource("../resources/mapred-site.xml");
        configuration.addResource("../resources/yarn-site.xml");
        return configuration;
    }

    @Override
    public void runJob() {
        Configuration conf = getConfiguration();
        try{
//            File jarFile = EJob.createTempJar("/home/ubuntu/");
            Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "My Count");
//            job.setJar(String.valueOf(jarFile));
//            ((JobConf) job.getConfiguration()).setJar(jarFile.toString());
            job.setJarByClass(com.letoy.main.utils.NameCount.class);
            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/data/text.txt"));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/output/resultCount"));

            job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setMapOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

            job.setOutputKeyClass(NameCount.NameCountBean.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);

            job.setMapperClass(NameCount.MyMapper.class);
            job.setReducerClass(NameCount.MyReducer.class);

            if (job.waitForCompletion(true)) {
                if (job.isSuccessful()) {
                    System.out.println("Job was successful");
                } else if (!job.isSuccessful()) {
                    System.out.println("Job was not successful");
                }
                System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I try sevral confs but they all failed.

Here is the NamesCount Source Code:

```
public class NameCount {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Job job = new Job();
        job.setJarByClass(NameCount.class);
        job.setJobName("nameCount");

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));


        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(NameCountBean.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);


        job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);


        int returnValue = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;

        if (job.isSuccessful()) {
            System.out.println("Job was successful");
        } else if (!job.isSuccessful()) {
            System.out.println("Job was not successful");
        }
    }

    public static class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable> {

        private LongWritable outV = new LongWritable(1);

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


            String line = value.toString();
            if (line == null || line.trim().length() == 0) {
                return;
            }
            String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
            for (String word : words) {
                if (word.contains("Sherlock")) {
                    context.write(new Text("Sherlock"), outV);
                } else if (word.contains("Watson")) {
                    context.write(new Text("Watson"), outV);
                } else if (word.contains("Jefferson")) {
                    context.write(new Text("Jefferson"), outV);
                }

            }


        }
    }


    public static class MyReducer extends Reducer<Text, LongWritable, NameCountBean, NullWritable> {


        @Override
        protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<LongWritable> values, Reducer<Text, LongWritable, NameCountBean, NullWritable>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            long sum = 0;
            for (LongWritable value : values) {
                sum += value.get();
            }
            NameCountBean nameCountBean = new NameCountBean();
            nameCountBean.setName(key.toString());
            nameCountBean.setCount(sum);
            context.write(nameCountBean, NullWritable.get());
        }
    }


    public static class NameCountBean implements WritableComparable<NameCountBean> {

        private String name;
        private long count;

        public NameCountBean() {

        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public long getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        public void setCount(long count) {
            this.count = count;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(NameCountBean o) {
            return Long.compare(count, o.count);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(DataOutput dataOutput) throws IOException {
            dataOutput.writeUTF(name);
            dataOutput.writeLong(count);

        }

        @Override
        public void readFields(DataInput dataInput) throws IOException {

            name = dataInput.readUTF();
            count = dataInput.readLong();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name+"\t"+count;
        }
    }

}
```

I set the jar using the job.setJarByClass but it didn't worked.
This is the error when running the application:
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.letoy.main.utils.NameCount$MyMapper not found

Comment: Show the full `com.letoy.main.utils.NameCount` java file

Comment: Hi, I added relevant information in the question.

Comment: Why can't you just call the main method of NameCount? You shouldn't need Spring boot

Comment: Yeah, I know. I've already tried to call the main method , it can works. But I'd like to figure out how to use it with Spring Boot.

Comment: Hi, I solved the problem. The reason is Spring's default package pulgin package all the things into the jar. So hadoop can not find the classes. Then I changed another plugin to package the jar. And it can work!

Comment: Feel free to put your answer below rather than as a comment